# Is injecting a TypeConverter safe for a framework type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is this wise?

```
class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter {
  // implementation
}

// elsewhere
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(string[]),
   new[] { new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(MyTypeConverter)) });
```

Note I'm putting this on `string[]`.

It feels dirty to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Safe?  Yes, it's used by the Windows Forms Designer to inject attributes so it's a valid piece of functionality, although not heavily used.

Dirty?  Yeah, a little bit.  If there's some other way of skinning the cat, I'd look at doing it that way.  Attributes are meant to be simple metadata used to provide a clean way to specify certain characteristics of your code.  By using dynamic attributes, you're kind of going out of the normal use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it, then you need to do it.  Be sure you don't really just need a readonly property on a containing class, though.

However, I would suggest using typeof (IEnumerable), so you can pick up lists, collections, etc., as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure importing namespaces with `using` has nothing dto do with what `TypeConverter` is used.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was answering two questions at once and got it turned around with extension methods. Mia culpa. (Answer edited).